# Does it possible to store sqlite's :memory: tables in APC?

Tags: php, sqlite, caching, apc, in-memory-database

After reading [PHP / SQLite - Copying a table from disk to memory](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1157996/php-sqlite-copying-a-table-from-disk-to-memory/2192160#2192160)
I must ask this question.

Let's say I have a web page that uses some data upon every page load, I want it to be in shared memory since the data could get large, APC could solve that. I need to be able to search the data and use aggregate functions etc.. so sql is the way to go.

The ultimate solution would be sqlite's :memory: table, but in PHP, such tables won't be persistent.

Does it possible to store sqlite's :memory: tables in APC?
Or any other solution to that problem?

Comment: Before going this route, note that an often accessed file will be cached in memory by the OS by default, so if the number of writes are not that high, there is probably not a real big gain in performance.

Comment: I don't believe temporary tables would help either: as far as I'm aware, SQLite holds those in memory where it can, but the PHP SQLite doesn't allow you to create them